# Запретить в CheckedListBox снятие галочки у выделенной строки

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить код ниже (vs2010 c# winforms), чтобы при повторном выделении одной и той же строки в CheckedListBox1 (не двойной клик) галочка не снималась.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            CheckedListBox1.Sorted = true;
            CheckedListBox1.TopIndex = 0;
            CheckedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
            CheckedListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
}

private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
            for (int ix = 0; ix < CheckedListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix)
            {
                if (ix != e.Index)
                {
                    CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```csharp
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
}
```

Ответ на комментарий ниже

```csharp
private void checkedListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас заметила, что если кликнуть все-таки два раза (быстро), то галочка снимается. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это отменить?

Comment: @olga добавьте событие двойного щелчка мыши как в примере выше.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!